# How to fix: unexpected tokens after copying xpath into script

Tags: r, xpath

I am trying to scrape company descriptions from a website. To access the company description, you have to click on the company name, and the site directs you to another page that is specific to the given company. In order to set up this loop, I need to copy over the x path, but I'm having trouble with the syntax, as I'm getting an unexpected token error. I'm new to coding so please answer as simply as possible.

```
number <- c(156000:165000)
description <- NULL
for(i in 1:949){
  url <- paste0("https://congress.nsc.org/nsc2019/public/eBooth.aspx?IndexInList=0&FromPage=Exhibitors.aspx&ParentBoothID=&ListByBooth=true&BoothID=", 
                number[i])

description[i] <- url %>%
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = paste(//*[@id="eboothContainer"]/p)) %>% 
  html_text()

}
```

Comment: Please show the error message and what causes the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below line

```
html_nodes(xpath = paste(//*[@id="eboothContainer"]/p)) %>%  # <== incorrect
```

as below

```
html_nodes(xpath = "//*[@id='eboothContainer']/p") %>% # <== correct
```

Just adjusted the xpath and the line of code.